# jQuery Phone Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use a regular expression to;

- only allow the user to type numbers and dash(-)
- when they type special character it will replace with dash(-)

> $(document).on("keydown","#ClinicPhone" , function(event){            var
>   str=$("#ClinicPhone").val();          str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'-');
>   });

I want this code raised on keydown event.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Can you post your html and validation function? Are you stuck just with the Regex or with the event handling?

Comment: give this plugin a try http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'-');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just mask you input text so that it only accepts correct input.

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#date").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"mm/dd/yyyy"});
   $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
   $("#tin").mask("99-9999999");
   $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999");
});
```

You have

```
jQuery(function($){
       $("#ClinicPhone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
    });
```

More sample and documention [here](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)